# Tips for debugging ruby on rails code flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having hard time debugging the flow of the  code on "Ruby on Rails". Please give me some tips. I'm new to "Ruby on rails". Like in php we use `var_dump,print_r and die`, just to check where the data has reached.

Comment: Tip: Go through the first few chapters of the freely available [Ruby on Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) to get a better understanding of how Rails works, as well as various tools and tricks while working with Ruby on Rails. The time spent on it will help you immensely in figuring out these types of things yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparable tricks in Ruby:

Output something to the server log (`log/development.log` by default).
I usually keep one terminal window watching the log whenever I'm developing. (`tail -f /log/development.log`)

You can use `puts` or `logger.info` to print things into the log, but personally I like [this gem, lll](https://github.com/mwilden/lll), which logs out nicely highlighted versions of whatever you pass it.

To stop execution, you can use `abort`or `raise`. E.g.:

```
raise "something terrible happened."
```

When you do this in development mode, as with any other exception, Rails renders a page with a bunch of handy stuff on it - the exception, a stack trace, and the current state of parameter, session and environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late but for your reference for print_r use the following:

abort Object.methods.inspect

Abort is the equivalent to die. The "methods" method will list all methods associated to an object. If you have an array and wish to output the array simply do:

abort Array.inspect

Comment: No problem, hope that helps.